# I disagree with the review that rejected this wiki tag edit. Is there channel to raise this issue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

A while back, I suggested the [following edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23708202) for `implicit-expansion`. I think the tag was created by a user with the intention of it being used for `Matlab`.

The central issue with the rejects is that "implicit expansion" is not a generic or common sense term. It is not a defined function in Matlab either. It is instead a general pattern of behaviors. The exact definitions depend on the array dimensions (and if one digs enough, perhaps it also depends on data type.)

Outer product is meant to be the pointer to what it means. (And I need to say "outer product like" because "outer product" is the closest defined terminology that describes the behavior but not exactly -- outer product as it applies to matrices, although now Google-able, still isn't a generic concept, and thus it is possible that some areas of study out there would use the term "outer product" to mean something similar yet different.)

From there, the intended usage is to apply the tag to any question that involves (Matlab) implicit expansion code phrase or to any question that desires to implement an outer product like behavior. In this case, the usage is actually common sense. The terminology is not.

`bsxfun` would be a related tag but that relation is version dependent. The intention here is several-fold: by leveraging `bsxfun`, an older Matlab function and an older tag, it helps explaining `implicit-explaining` -- again, the term is *not* common sense; by leveraging `bsxfun`, which has been tagged often, `implicit-expansion` can be tagged in similar situations. Later on, tags involving these special syntax/facilities can give an overview of the sort of problems they tend to solve.

I am not sure if it would be better or worse for the tag to be `Matlab-implicit-expansion`. In any case, that format is not used for any of the other Matlab-esque functions or facilities.

All in all, the wiki edit complies with general [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts). It is a meaningful improvement to not having the edit.

It should not have been rejected.

What is the proper channel to dispute/reverse the reject?

And I think this alludes to a bigger issue: I am not sure if the reviewers truly took the time to understand the tag. If they did, they should see the tag without explanation is not being useful; yet with explanation it could be. If they wish to highlight usage guidance with wording changes, they could in a subsequent edit to the wiki.

In questions and answers, since vote to close and vote to delete usually result in an automatic comment, they offer the author an implicit opportunity to dispute/explain why a reviewer's decision should not apply to their question/answer. And since both the reason and the responding comment can be seen, as well as their upvotes, subsequent reviewers may incorporate those exchanges in their concurring/dissenting votes.

Yet, Wiki tag edits don't provide the channels. How can that be improved?

And is the automatic category for rejections in wiki tag review decentivizing reviewers to study the wiki edits + the tags?

Comment: That channel is called Meta. So... welcome

Comment: The tag excerpts are meant to guide how to use the tag itself, the excerpt is not for a feature description.

Comment: That edit is the the _excerpt_, not the wiki, the excerpt should describe how and when a tag should be used.

Comment: @Nick: TBH I remember being confused with two sections in the tag edit session...

Comment: The tag was also created by you, not some user

Comment: @Zoe: It's been a while. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Argyll Yes, I think that's a common issue, there's 2 _distinct_ parts to a tag wiki, the excerpt and the wiki itself. The excerpt has a very specific purpose in comparison to the wiki.

Answer (score 7):

Meta (this site) is *the place* to discuss such issues.

Yes, the edit is correctly rejected because it is not a tag wiki edit.

The edit in question is an edit to create the "tag excerpt". It is primarily expected to describe *when* tag should be used (like "foo-lang should be used for questions about Foo language. Don't confuse with 'Foo.js' and 'Foo-tlong Subway sandwiches'.") The edit described what the tag is about instead - it could be considered as possible one for the "tag Wiki", although usually wiki information is a bit longer.

Following would probably be better:

> Use this tag for MatLab related questions involving Implicit expansion (including use of functions such as bsxfun) in addition to MatLab tag.

If you know that tag likely be misused for something else then consider adding a sentence about that too "Don't use for implicit conversions between types in other languages".

Guidance: [Wiki Excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) (already linked in the question).